# assign ip adress dynamically in jsf2 application to show images from local server remotely

Tags: image, dynamic, jsf-2, primefaces, webserver

here is my p:graphcimage :

```
<p:commandLink id="mylink" onclick="ajouterUpload();">
            <h:graphicImage id="Ajouterimage"
                value="http://localhost:8080/images/#{articlesMB.article.photo}" height="64"
                width="64" />
        </p:commandLink>
```

when I access application from remote machine I must replace localhost by 41.122.100.234
and this ip change each time

is there any way to assig it dinamycally

I use spring and jsf2

Comment: I can not imagine your problem, you fixed your path, why don't you use requescontext path ?

Comment: Why on earth are you using absolute path?? You need to read this http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/